# give 404 if GET method is not supported

Tags: php, laravel

I have a POST method in my route

```
Route::post('blog/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@sendGrade');
```

And when I also specify POST in the request, then everything is fine

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
```

But when the request is GET, I will get an error

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

This is all obvious, but is it possible to avoid this so that if there is a GET method in the request, then instead of this error I would get a 404 error?

As far as I understand it can be done in the controller. Right now I have something like this when the entry doesn't exist

```
if(!$blog){
  return abort(404);
}
```

Is it possible to do the same for the GET method?

Comment: You *shouldn't*: The URL points to a real resource. The [405 Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/status/405) response that your router is presumably outputting by default is correct. 404 Not Found is incorrect.

Comment: If it's a web request, you can change the [Error Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#the-exception-handler) to point the view to a generic 404 message. Your browser will still send back a 405, but to a normal user, it will look like a 404.

Comment: @aynber I don't quite understand where I need to apply it

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve?  Why would you recieve.a GET request?

Comment: The solution is to always send the correct `POST` request type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this route to your web.php file

```
Route::get('blog/{id}', function () {
            abort(404);
 });
```

this will work 100%

Comment: Will this look exactly as an unregistered route? Say make GET /something the result should be exactly the same

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-abort The abort function throws an HTTP exception which will be rendered by the exception handler:  Meaning also logged.

Comment: this will check after you find a method(get or post),but if you want to perform some code then there is no need to abort().

Comment: so i think this will work if you want to abort for get route

Comment: If you have a load balancer or an ngnx in front, those will give you a different 404 than your laravel gives you. That is why I asked. Will the html page loaded in the browser be exactly the same if you just throw an 404 exception (your abort is doing just that)?

Comment: for that you don't need to abort

Comment: Nevermind. You don't understant.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'blog/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@sendGrade');

/**
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function sendGrade(string $id, Request $request): Response
{
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'GET') {
        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
    }
 
    // code
}
```

in the exceptions/handler.php

```
protected $dontReport = [
    NotFoundHttpException::class
];

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function render($request, \Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        try {
            /** @var Client $guzzleClient */
            $guzzleClient = \resolve(Client::class); // register the Client in appServiceProviders.php as singleton for example
            $result = $guzzleClient->get('/getNotFoundEndpoint');
            $body = $result->getBody()->getContents();
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        }

        return \response($body ?? '', 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```